# Cannot make a cache safe URL

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, sharepoint-server, app-catalog

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this ?
Having an issue on Virtual Machine, on all sites. This file isn't available on all machine.

The file is present in

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1036

and

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033

> Cannot make a cache safe URL for
> "15/16.0.10345.12101/1033/initstrings.js", file not found. Please
> verify that the file exists under the layouts directory. Description:
> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
> web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
> the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot make a cache safe URL for "15/16.0.10345.12101/1033/initstrings.js", file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

> [SPException: Cannot make a cache safe URL for
> "15/16.0.10345.12101/1033/initstrings.js", file not found. Please
> verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.]
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl(String
> name, String sideBySideToken, Boolean localizable, Int32
> desiredVersion) +5694
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLinkInfo.ToScriptUrl(Boolean
> useDebugJs) +792
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLinkInfo.ToScriptBlock(Page
> page) +23
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RenderScriptBlockInternal(Control
> ctrl, Page page, Boolean afterUI, HtmlTextWriter writer, Boolean
> deltaPage, Boolean noRenderAxdScripts, Boolean renderJSLinkScript)
> +1071    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RenderScriptBlock(Control
> ctrl, Page page, HtmlTextWriter writer, Boolean afterUI, Boolean
> noRenderAxdScripts, Boolean renderJSLinkScript) +92
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +306
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ControlAdapter adapter) +79
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ICollection children) +250
> System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +27
> System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +47
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ControlAdapter adapter) +79
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ICollection children) +250
> System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +47
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ControlAdapter adapter) +79
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ICollection children) +250
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ControlAdapter adapter) +79
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ICollection children) +250    System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +39
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +846
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +347
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +24
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> writer) +199
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ControlAdapter adapter) +79
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +8753

Answer (score 0):

The 'cache safe URL' message is something you can ignore, but not the missing file issue. It sounds like the patches aren't consistent from server-to-server. Ideally, can you deploy https://support.microsoft.com/help/4486675 and https://support.microsoft.com/help/4486676 to your farm? These are the updated for October 2020.

Comment: Sorry, i updated the location of files.

Comment: Same answer applies. Note that if the last patch you have deployed is from May 2019, your farm will be unsupported as of 10/30/2020. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/product-servicing-policy/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-2019. Best solution is to update to the October 2020 PU, which I linked to in my answer.

Comment: I applied both, i still have the same issue.

Comment: Did you run the Config Wizard on each farm member?

Comment: Yes applied, I don't why the error is refering to 15/16.0.10345.12101/

Comment: It's due to the side by side feature. You can try using `Copy-SPSidebySideFiles` on that farm member.